# variable not being found inside click jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, variables, click

I have a list of some radio buttons, I get the value of the checked input on click, store it in a variable, and later I want to access the variable when another element, e.g a div is clicked. Everything works fine except for the variable not being recognized inside the second click event. Maybe a possible variable scope mistake?

```
   <ul><li><a href="#">Line</a><input class="checkTool" type="radio" name="drawTool"     value="line"></input></li></ul>
            <ul><li><a href="#">Rect</a><input class="checkTool" type="radio" name="drawTool" value="rectangle"></input></li></ul>
            <ul><li><a href="#">Circ</a><input class="checkTool" type="radio" name="drawTool" value="circle"></input></li></ul>
```

​

```
 $("input:radio[name=drawTool]").click(function() {
                    var currTool = $(this).val();
 });


$('.space').click(function(){


$(this).html(currTool)

})
```

​[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/menislici/cbfhu/3/)

Comment: Why U no learn what is a variable scope and how variables are being used?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath sorry, i meant to type the variable. I actually did in the fiddle though, it's just a typo in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access in a different method, keep the value in a  variable declared outside the method. So that it has a wider scope than the method. It can be accessible outside the method as well.

```
$(function(){

   var currTool="";
   $("input:radio[name=drawTool]").click(function() {
      currTool= $(this).val();
   });

   $('.space').click(function(){
      $(this).html(currTool)
   })

});
```

Comment: That's not a global variable, it's declared within the scope of the (outer) anonymous function. (Which is actually _better_ than a global for this purpose since it is the nearest scope that the inner functions have access to.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: Ah ! Changed the sentence

Comment: Still, there's no need to keep track of the current tool with a variable. You can always, at any given point in time, retrieve the currently checked item with a `:checked` pseudo-selector as demonstrated in my answer below. Instead, you're trying to reinvent the wheel by manually recording check state changes, and you're not even covering all cases: you're not taking into account keyboard input with arrow keys, tab and/or space bar or other means of navigating web pages such as screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

Even better: you can retrieve the currently selected tool when you actually need it by looking for the *checked* radio button.

```
$('.space').click(function(){
    var currTool = $("input:radio[name=drawTool]:checked").val();
    $(this).html(currTool);
});
```

Comment: note: this is a lot better, as clicking is not the only action which can change the state of the input.